# moving an object around a Circle

Tags: mathematics, graphics-programming, lua

I am going to draw a shape like a gear, how can I move a tooth around a circle?
Something like the image below : [image: circle]

For example, I need to draw 20 teeth at equal intervals around a circle with a diameter of 50 mm.
I am doing this for a G-code generator program
I draw a tooth first ,Then it is necessary to draw these teeth, which can be adjusted to the desired number by the user, according to the diameter of the gear wheel around a circle
For example, this is a G-code for drawing one tooth :

```
G90
G21
G1 X0 Y0 
G1 X5 Y10
G1 X10 Y10
G1 X15 Y0
```

You can view the output using this site :
https://ncviewer.com/

What is the equation to do this?
I am currently programming using Lua language

Comment: Game developers are usually not experts in G-code. What led you to ask this question here, rather than on a machining StackExchange site like [Engineering.StackExchange](https://engineering.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/cnc)?

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because it is a cross-post from [SO](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/76063483/moving-an-object-around-a-circle). Cross-posting is not allowed on SE sites; select the site you think will give you the best/most answers and ask only there.

Answer (score 2):

This is a pretty conventional application of a transformation matrix.

First, we need a matrix that translates the center of the gear to the origin:

$$\mathbb{T} = \begin{bmatrix}
1 & 0 & -C_x\\
0 & 1 & -C_y\\
0 & 0 & 1
\end{bmatrix}$$

Then we rotate by the desired angle \$\theta\$ around the origin:

$$\mathbb{R}_\theta = \begin{bmatrix}
\cos \theta & -\sin \theta & 0\\
\sin \theta & \cos \theta & 0\\
0 & 0 & 1
\end{bmatrix}$$

Then we reverse our translation to put the whole gear back where we started.

Composing these matrices, we get...

$$\begin{align}\vec v^\prime &= \mathbb T^{-1}\mathbb R_\theta \mathbb T \vec v\\
&= \begin{bmatrix}1 & 0 & C_x\\0&1&C_y\\0&0&1\end{bmatrix}
\begin{bmatrix}\cos \theta & -\sin \theta & 0\\\sin \theta & \cos \theta & 0\\0&0&1\end{bmatrix}
\begin{bmatrix}1 & 0 & -C_x\\0&1&-C_y\\0&0&1\end{bmatrix}\begin{bmatrix}v_x\\v_y\\1\end{bmatrix}\\
&= \begin{bmatrix}\cos \theta & -\sin \theta & C_x\\\sin \theta & \cos \theta & C_y\\0&0&1\end{bmatrix}
\begin{bmatrix}1 & 0 & -C_x\\0&1&-C_y\\0&0&1\end{bmatrix}\begin{bmatrix}v_x\\v_y\\1\end{bmatrix}\\
&= \begin{bmatrix}\cos \theta & -\sin \theta & -C_x\cos \theta + C_y \sin \theta + C_x \\\sin \theta & \cos \theta & -C_x \sin \theta - C_y \cos \theta + C_y\\0&0&1\end{bmatrix}
\begin{bmatrix}v_x\\v_y\\1\end{bmatrix}\\
&= \begin{bmatrix}v_x \cos \theta - v_y \sin \theta -C_x\cos \theta + C_y \sin \theta + C_x\\v_x \sin \theta + v_y \cos \theta -C_x \sin \theta - C_y \cos \theta + C_y \\1\end{bmatrix}\\
\end{align}$$

That gives you the formula for the x and y coordinates of a point \$\vec v\$ after this transformation. You can ignore the third row - it's just there to make the translation work.

Whether there's a nicer way to do this in G-code is a question for someone other than a game developer.